# Icon is not visible on release task catalog in Azure DevOps pipeline. vss-extension.json as below,

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "build-release-task",
    "name": "",
    "version": "1.1.9",
    "publisher": " ",
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],    
    "description": "",
    "categories": [
        "Azure Pipelines"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "images/extension-icon.png"      
    },
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "buildAndReleaseTask"
        },
        {
            "path": "images",
            "addressable": true

        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "custom-build-release-task",
            "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "buildAndReleaseTask",
                "icon": "images/extension-icon.png"

            }

        }
    ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should put the icon file also in the task folder (where the `.ts`/`.ps1` files).

Comment: The extension i am creating doesn't have .ts or .ps1 file. its simple extension which gives cmd feature. i tried putting icon file where task.json but didn't resolve problem.

Comment: Can you share your folders and files structure?

Comment: I am unable to attach screenshots of folder/file structure. What i have tried is, i have placed icon in folder where task.json is available and gave to path to icon in manifest file. Also tried same with creating new image folder and gave path to icon.

Comment: It should work but maybe you miss something, I really need to see the folders and flies.